# Avano Theme Woocommerce Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am having some problems on Avano Theme.
I dont know which plug-in's I need to use, I cant make the design of the homepage like the original... Please, I need some help, if anyone know how to work with this, I appreciate the contact.

If you need more information to give an answer, just ask.

link1: https://themeforest.net/item/avano-multipurpose-woocommerce-theme/15872390

link2: http://ninethemes.net/avano/wordpress/1/

Comment: stackoverflow isn't the proper place to ask support for a commercial product. You should request help from the developers of the theme.

Comment: okok! Roger that